# Prisma Client not working with Angular 17

Tags: angular, postgresql, server-side-rendering, prisma, angular17-ssr

I am building an angular 17 application with SSR enabled at the time of project initialization.
I am trying to use Prisma ORM to fetch data from Postgresql DB.
I am able to set up Prisma, my `schema.prisma` file is created with all the schemas from the D.B., and in the Prisma studio, I can view all the table entries from the DB.

I have created a service to fetch data from DB using Prisma and injected this service on the frontend, in a component and received the following error:

**Service.ts**

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  PrismaClient
} from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class OrmService {
  private prisma: PrismaClient = new PrismaClient();
  constructor() {}

  getMovies() {
    const predictions = this.prisma.movies;
    console.log(predictions, 'clg pred');
    return predictions;
  }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```js
import {
  Component,
  inject
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  OrmService
} from '../../services/dbservice/orm.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './categories.component.html',
  styleUrl: './categories.component.scss',
})
export class CategoriesComponent {
  prismaService = inject(OrmService);

  item!: any;
  predictions!: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.prismaService.getMovies();
  }
}
```

[image]